# Google Lite map displays a lot more information than normal one

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on switching a normal Google Map view to lite mode and found a number of unwanted difference (in my situation) - see the screenshots:

Lite Mode:
[image: Lite mode]

Normal Mode:
[image]

- With the same `LatLingZoom` value, the map seem to be zoomed at difference levels
- The lite mode map seems to show more details than the normal mode map

I was wondering if there is any settings we could do to make the lite mode map identical with the normal mode one?

Answer (score 0):

You can see a lot of things because of the zoomed view. You can set the zoom level like this -

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 12.0f));

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that ,
first check if the zoom levels are same.

if not you can manage map details by setting custom style which can be done [here](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/)
You can adjust density of roads , landmarks and labels